# How to setup first time launch of an iOS App

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

I want to show the terms and conditions only the first time of my app launch.

Currently I am writing my code in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
// Handle launching from a notification
 if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"])
{
    NSLog(@"Already Run");
}
else
{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];

FirstPage * termsView = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FirstPage"];

    UINavigationController *navController=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:termsView];
    self.window.rootViewController=navController;

    // This is the first launch ever
}
}
```

UPDATE::

What I want when my application launched first time in `TERMSandCONDITIONSVC` I have an `Accept` Button. When User `Accepts` the aggrement then only He allowed go further.

Problem With Above Code:

When i run my app first time `TermsandCondition` displayed to me.I press home button the app goes in Background.Again I open The app from launcher and `TermsandCondtion` showed.

But When I put my app in Background and By adouble tapping Home button remove it from background and run the app I am directly transfered to my home screen.

No terms and conditions.

How Can i recover from this.

Comment: Application needs one view as Root view controller so you will need to set up rootview controller regardless of if else condition. This means you need to set RootView Controller in your if condition as well

Comment: @AadilKeshwani see my story board..I have already set. I want to only change it when my app runs first time. See my screenshot

Comment: You can try following code: 

`FirstPage * termsView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"termsView"]; 

UINavigationController *navController=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:termsView];
self.window.rootViewController=navController;`

Make sure to give `termsView` as storyboard id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting black screen because no viewcontroller is set as root view.

Do one thing Write your **else** part in **IF** part also and change your controller from terms page to second page.

Try to put below code in didFinishLaunch and check.

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds];

UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];

UINavigationController *navController

 if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"])
{
    NSLog(@"Already Run");
    SecondView *secondView = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:<storyboard id>];
    navController=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:secondView];

}
else
{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

     TermsView *termsView = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:<storyboard id>];
    navController=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:termsView];

// This is the first launch ever
    }
}
self.window.rootViewController=navController;
 return YES;
```

UPDATE: 
just drag below lines to agree button's click event and remove this lines from didFinishlaunching.

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Comment: can you write you didFinishLaunch method Code in Question

Comment: I updated my questions...and please tell me is didFinishLaunchingWithOptions is correct place to check launch of the application

Comment: then what i am doing wrong. Is something wrong in my code.

Comment: @RahulMishra is there any control added in your view? Because in story board i can't seen any control

Comment: You don't need to do the same thing for the default root view controller. That will be called automatically.

Comment: @MalavSoni I have Updated My Question Please have a look

Answer (score 1):

You are instantiating your `termsView` in a wrong manner. In your storyboard assign the `FirstPage` view controller a storyboardID of `FirstPage`.

And then in your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` do the following

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];

FirstPage * termsView = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FirstPage"];
```

This will find your main storyboard and then instantiate `termsView` with the ViewController based on the storyboardID provided(i.e. `FirstPage`).

Comment: is didFinishLaunchingWithOptions correct place to write this code ?

Comment: I have Updated My Question Please have a look

Answer (score 1):

If you want to setup first time launch of an iOS app. Using this code the terms and conditions will appears or shown only the first time of app launch.

```
  if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"])
    {
        NSLog(@"Already Run");
    }
    else
    {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
        FirstPage *termsView = [[FirstPage alloc]init];

        UINavigationController *navController=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:termsView];
        self.window.rootViewController=navController;

        // This is the first launch ever
UIStoryboard *story=[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
//first goto storyboard and give storyboard id "TermsConditionVC" to TermsConditionVC 
        TermsConditionVC *firstVC = [story instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TermsConditionVC"];
        self.window.rootViewController =firstVC;
    }
```

for full article and complete process to setup your first timer iOS app launch visit below link
http://findnerd.com/list/view/How-to-setup-first-time-launch-of-an-iOS-App/2770/